# Produce a 64 character long password from a RSA private key

Tags: password, openssl

I need a reproducible way to generate the same password from an RSA private key and should not depend on the OpenSSL version and other thing that like a file format...

Thanks!

EDIT1:

```
openssl dgst -sha256 -sign private.key -out signature /dev/null
```

I would like to know if the signature file will stay exactly the same (at the nearest octet) if I retry this command in the future?

EDIT2:

In fact I have a PKI which generate one key for each system used for the secure boot to sign the EFI image (EFI stub + kernel + initrd). The system need to have the hand on the private key to regenerate the EFI image for each kernel upgrade.
The private key is stored on the LUKS encrypted rootfs, un locked on the boot with the TPM.

The need: I would like to produce a 512bits long key, derived from the RSA key and stored on a LUKS slot, to be able to unlock my encrypted container with in additional to the TPM one.

With this, I can recover an encrypted disk from a crashed system, using the corresponded RSA private key from the PKI database.

Comment: OK, this question, together with the comments under bs-'s answer, really sound like you're doing something unwise, cryptographically/security-wise. Please explain *why* you want to do this. You, in general, would *never* give out information about a private key. Never. You'd even avoid carrying out in any form any verifiable identifier of that private key, aside from the public key. And: the private key is the private key. That doesn't change over time. The container format for it might change, but the actual  bits of the key stay the same, so I'm not sure where any problem ever arises from.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I had added some details on the context

Comment: @MarcusMüller I need the OpenSSL command to extract the actual bits of the key and generate a unique and reproducible signature.

Comment: Thanks! So it's not a password, but a LUKS recovery key! So, if that's the case and you have an orderly database, why does the recovery key need to be derived from the private key? Can't it just be random?

Comment: Btw, just encrypting some data with the private key would go as signature.

Comment: "encrypting some data" : indeed, it's a good idea...

Comment: @MarcusMüller Yes I would like to avoid making an additional database for this...

Comment: @MarcusMüller I think that RSA encryption is only done with the public key and not the private one and the public key is readable by anybody and stored in the UEFI certificate database... :/ For this reason, (EDIT 1) I have mentioned the idea of the signature, but I don't know if the signature format will change in the future...

Comment: Again, you don't care about the format. The bits of the cryptographic payload can't change.

Comment: and again, deriving the recovery key from a key that the device might leak unnecessarily weakens your storage encryption. I would simply *not do it* if all the cost is having a "database" (a folder with files containing randomly generated recovery keys named after the machine/the private key?) of recovery keys.

Answer (score 0):

Applying a cryptographic hash function to the RSA private key is a reproducible way to generate a password from the key.

The key cannot be recovered from the hash due to the properties of cryptographic hash functions.

Whether this approach is desirable will depend on the broader context.

Comment: Welcome to U&L. You need to add more explainations.

Comment: @GAD3R I'd love too, but the question is rather vague.

Comment: Yes, I had thinking about it, but the problem is to ensure to have the key in raw format from the PEM format and be ensured that I have the same result in the future with the same PEM key and another version of OpenSSL.

Comment: To avoid flagging your answer as very quality.

Comment: @EmericVerschuur Why are you finding it difficult to use the key in raw format?

Comment: There is a way to extract the private key in a raw format with OpenSSL from an RSA private key in PEM format?

Comment: There is a DER format but I am uncertain if this format will change a bit in the future which will have an impact on the hash...

Comment: You're right to be concerned about formats, indeed, any malleable format will cause problems. Extracting the raw private key avoids such formatting issues. Regarding your application, are you sure it's a good idea to be using a private key this way? Perhaps you can explain your application?

Comment: @bs yes, in fact I just have a private key and I need a way to produce the same passphrase independently of the environment. The private key is the only way to identify the platform.

Comment: @EmericVerschuur what? How can the private key be used to *identify* a platform?! Then it's not a *private* key!

Comment: @GAD3R not sure what you're getting at, the answer is accurate, on point and there's nothing it leaves unclear.

Comment: @MarcusMüller The OP should probably have written: The private key is the only way to *authenticate* the platform.